# Character reading after the integer

Tags: c

I tried a simple calculator exercise. Even though I got the logic right. I was struggling to find why I couldn't read a character after two integers in it.

Not working code given below (getting the numbers first then the operation as character). But in the same code if I read the character first then the numbers it is working all good. Not getting the logic behind this :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void add (unsigned int temp1, unsigned int temp0);
void subtract (unsigned int temp1, unsigned int temp0);
void multiply (unsigned int *temp);
void divide (unsigned int *temp);

int main()
{
    unsigned int num[2];
    char op;

    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%u", &num[0]);
    scanf("%u", &num[1]);
   
    printf("Enter operation\n");
    scanf("%c", &op);

    switch(op)
    {
        case '+': add(num[0],num[1]);
        break;

        case '-': subtract(num[0],num[1]);
        break;

        case '*': multiply(num);
        break;

        case '/': divide(num);
        break;

        default: printf("Invalid Operation");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}


void add (unsigned int temp1, unsigned int temp0)
{
    printf("Sum of the numbers is: %u", temp1+temp0);
}

void multiply (unsigned int *temp)
{
    printf("Product of the numbers is: %u", temp[0]*temp[1]);
}

void subtract (unsigned int temp1, unsigned int temp0)
{
    if (temp1 > temp0)
    {
        printf("Difference of the numbers is: %u", temp1-temp0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Difference of the numbers is: %u", temp0-temp1);
    }
}

void divide (unsigned int *temp)
{
    unsigned int quo;
    unsigned int rem;
    
    quo = temp[0]/temp[1];
    rem = temp[0]%temp[1];
    
    printf("Quotient of %u divided by %u is: %u\n", temp[0], temp[1], quo);
    printf("Remainder of %u divided by %u is: %u\n", temp[0], temp[1], rem);
}
```

Comment: You should provide sample input and actual vs. expected output/results.

Comment: xing Thanks it works. But why is it not a problem when the character was read first. Like this.         printf("Enter operation\n");
    scanf("%c", &op); printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%u", &num[0]);
    scanf("%u", &num[1]);

Comment: `scanf("%c", &op);` will read a character without skipping initial whitespace no matter when you call it. If you input a space before the real operation character then `op` will be set to the space character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Now I am able to understand where I went wrong. Able to correct now.

Answer (score 0):

We are just guessing as we don't exactly know what you want to achieve. If you want to skip reading the new line character, then you can use the suggestion of ***Ian Abbot***.

By making the following change:

```
scanf("%c", &op); // Change this line
scanf(" %c", &op); // To this
```

This should solve your problem.